# Ajuda com loop While em Python

Tags: python-3.x, while

Já tentei diversas vezes, consigo imprimir a maior quantidade, consigo imprimir a data da maior venda, meu problema é na hora do laço,  código segue o laço como esta no comando, só quando ele quer, me ajudem , passei horas tentando achar o erro.

> 5. Uma loja de discos anota diariamente durante o mês de março a quantidade de discos vendidos. Determinar em que dia desse mês ocorreu a maior venda e qual foi a quantidade de discos vendida nesse dia.

Segue o código:

```
def main():

 qtd=int(input("Informe a quantidade"))

valor=2

 i=1

 dia=0

 maior=0

 while i <=5:

 maior=qtd

 i = i + 1

 qtd = int(input("Informe a quantidade"))

 if maior > qtd:

 maior_qtd=maior

 dia=i-1

 maior_venda=maior_qtd*valor

 print("A maior venda foi {} ".format(maior_qtd))

 print("O valor da maior venda foi {}R$ ".format(maior_venda))

 print("A maior venda foi no dia {}/3".format(dia))


main()
```

Resultado :

> ```
> Informe a quantidade 9
> Informe a quantidade 4
> A maior venda foi 9 
> O valor da maior venda foi 18R$ 
> A maior venda foi no dia 1/3
> Informe a quantidade
> ```

O laço é de 1 até 5 - e ele só faz duas repetições.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Falta identação no código, mas não vou te julgar por causa disso. Bem, li a pergunta e desenvolvi algo parecido em cima e com comentários para a explanação de algumas dúvidas.
   Tentei ser o mais fiel a seu código, mudei alguns nomes de variáveis, tratei as coisas um pouco diferente. Estude-o e mande o feedback, por favor.

**OBS:** "Determinar em que dia desse mês ocorreu a maior venda e qual foi a quantidade de discos vendida nesse dia." Por isso não coloquei a valor como no caso você colocou, mas é isso. Serve de base para estudo. Abraços irmão!

```
def main():
# Definindo as variaveis
  maior_venda         = int
  dia                 = int

# Atribundo Variaveis
  i           = 1 # Variavel que auxilia no ciclo
  maior_venda = 0 # maior venda == 0 pois não existe maior venda antes de vender algo.

  while i <= 5:

    qtd_vendida = int(input("Informe a quantidade de discos vendidos: ")) # Esse input trabalha com o ciclo, nao necessita de algo fora.

    if(qtd_vendida > maior_venda): # Verificamos se quantidade vendida e maior. Caso sim, atribua o valor a maior venda
        maior_venda = qtd_vendida #atribuimos a maior_venda a maior quantidade vendida
        dia = i # aqui ele verifica a posicao de i, caso quantidade vendida > que a maior venda anterior atribui a dia.

    i += 1; # adiciona +1 a variavel (i), controlando o ciclo.

  print("A maior quantidade de discos vendidos foi: {} discos".format(maior_venda))
  print("A maior quantidade de vendas foi feita dia: {}/MAR".format(dia))

main()
```

> **Teste 1:**
>       Informe a quantidade de discos vendidos: 25 
>       Informe a quantidade de discos vendidos: 10 
>       Informe a quantidade de discos vendidos: 50 
>       Informe a quantidade de discos vendidos: 39 
>       Informe a quantidade de discos vendidos: 40 
>       A maior quantidade de discos vendidos foi: 50 
>       A maior quantidade de vendas foi feita dia: 3/MAR
>
> **Teste 2:**
>       Informe a quantidade de discos vendidos: 12 
>       Informe a quantidade de discos vendidos: 50 
>       Informe a quantidade de discos vendidos: 34 
>       Informe a quantidade de discos vendidos: 89 
>       Informe a quantidade de discos vendidos: 90 
>       A maior quantidade de discos vendidos foi: 90 
>       A maior quantidade de vendas foi feita dia: 5/MAR

Comment: Desculpa pela falta de identação, primeira vez que eu publico, aconteceu de eu copiar e colar, e não me atentei a esse fato.Muito obrigado por me ajudar, tenho umas dificuldades bem grotescas em aplicar a lógica, e a forma como você escreveu seu código com os comentários, foram perfeitos.

Comment: Eu cadastrei ontem aqui, também não sabia mexer direito. Editei o post umas 10x hehehehe, mas muito bom saber que conseguiu entender amigo. Espero ter ajudado e boa sorte com seus projetos!

Comment: Muito obrigado irmão, ajudou e muito !

Answer (score -3):

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

```
//Variaveis:
int v,m=0,i,dm;

for(i=1 ; i<=30 ; i++){
    printf("\nDia %d      Total = ", i);
    scanf("%d",&v);
    if ( v >= m){
        m = v;
        dm = i;
    }
}
printf("\n Dia %d Total %d",dm,m);
```

}