# Iteração usando "while"

Tags: python, python-2.7, while

Tenho um pouco de dificuldade para entender `while` e me deparei com um exercício que pedia para fazer o seguinte:

Ler N sequencias e descobrir quantos 'f' tem em cada sequência. Não posso usar o `for` nessa questão.

Meu código ficou assim:

```
i = 0
faltas = 0

while True:
    registros = raw_input()
    if registros == '-':
        break

    while i < len(registros):
        if registros[i] == 'f':
            faltas += 1

        i += 1


    print faltas
```

O problema é que se eu digitar uma sequência que tem menos 'f's do que a anterior ele não mostra a quantidade de faltas da sequencia.

Ex:

```
.f.f.f.f
faltas = 4

.f.f..
faltas = 4 (onde deveria imprimir 2)
```

Comment: Voce sabe ler a sintaxe while ? verifique se isso ajudar a entender https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220915/ajuda-com-loop-while-em-python

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

O primeiro problema é que inicializa as variáveis de controle e acumuladora de faltas no início do algoritmo, mas quando termina de entrar a primeira vez elas não são zeradas, então para isto ocorrer precisa colocar a inicialização dentro do laço principal.

Existe um problema na verificação de saída, tem que analisar só o primeiro caractere para saber se é um traço, e não todo o texto.

```
while True:
    registros = raw_input()
    if registros[0] == '-':
        break
    i = 0
    faltas = 0
    while i < len(registros):
        if registros[i] == 'f':
            faltas += 1
        i += 1
    print faltas
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/570fZt). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/umgvhrlg-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/LoopInit.py).

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas! Deu certo aqui. Ainda sou novo na programação kkkk

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o método [`str.count`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) para calcular a quantidade de `f` na sua sequência:

```
while True:
    sequencia = raw_input('Digite uma sequência: ')
    if sequencia:
        print('Possui {} faltas na sequência'.format(sequencia.count('f')))
    else:
        break
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/AgreeableDizzyFirmware)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

[TL;DR](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/loop-while?language=python3)

Tente assim:

```
def count_f(registros):
  faltas, i = 0, 0
  while i < len(registros):
    if registros[i] == 'f':
        faltas += 1

    i += 1
  return faltas

while True:
  registros = input()
  if registros == '-':
      break

  print(count_f(registros))
```

Teste:

```
[aasfff
3
werf
1
asdfgffff
5
```

Veja funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/loop-while?language=python3)

Comment: Interessante: a pessoa dar um downvote mas não explicar o motivo.